UV Map of cylinderical model of rock core sample
I am a beginner user of Blender. I have 3D models of my core samples (rocks) created in Agisoft Metashape, and I want to create UV maps for them in Blender. However, when I attempt to do this, the UV map appears black and disrupts the original texture of my model.
Is there anyone who can help me with this? I’m not very familiar with Blender, but I really need assistance.
Thank you!
